# Covary two dummy variables in SEM?

Tags: categorical-data, structural-equation-modeling

I am running a structural equation model (SEM) in Amos 18, and I want to test the impact of marital status on several latent variables. Marital status is nominal, so I created three dummy variables:

1. Mar_Single: 1 = yes, 0 = no
2. Mar_Married: 1 = yes, 0 = no
3. Mar_Other: 1 = yes, 0 = no

I included Mar_Single and Mar_Married in the SEM, so their coefficients will be interpreted against the omitted (reference) group, Mar_Other. The modification indices suggested fit could be improved significantly if I covary Mar_Single and Mar_Married. Should I do this? In a way, this makes sense because they are perfectly correlated: If Mar_Single = 1 then Mar_Married will always = 0.

Larry

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should. You should always correlate exogenous variables - their correlations are not part of the model, and if you don't, you're either worsening fit, or getting degrees of freedom (which appear to improve fit) when you shouldn't.

When you do this in regression analysis, they are correlated (and there's no way of stopping them).

Also, you say "If Mar_Single = 1 then Mar_Married will always = 0."  Yes, but that doesn't make them perfectly correlated - because if mar_single = 0 mar_married might be 0 or might be 1.

If you use Mplus, it will correlate x-variables by default and will not include these correlations in the null model which it uses to calculate CFI and NFI.

Comment: Thank you for the great response. However, I am confused by this:

"You should always correlate exogenous variables ..."

Everything I've read on the subject (e.g., Byrne's book on SEM with AMOS, etc.) says to correlate variables only if doing so is supported by theory and empirical results (like modification indices). Have I misinterpreted the literature?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that book. If you're doing something analogous to regression, you should correlate predictors or you'll get incorrect estimates.

Comment: You mentioned in Mplus the default is to correlate xs. Why might a model fit improve if you explicitly mention with statements between xs rather than not explicitly mentioning them? Note, in this case simply the addition of a with statement between xs made model fit improve, coefficients remain the same.

Comment: Mentioning that changes it so it is considered part of the model, and the df count changes - I think the null model might also change. What changes? Loglikelihood shouldn't, nor should rmsea (I think). Does chi-square, df, cfi?